# Uploading file using Managed client object model in sharepoint 2013

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2013, csom

I have devloped the file uploading into document library in sharepoint 2013 using Managed client object model.
  Here iS my upload.aspx

```
        <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication7.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

        <div>

            <table>

                <tr>

                    <td colspan="2" align="center">

                        <asp:Label Font-Bold="true" Text="Upload a documents to SharePoint 2013" runat="server" ID="lblSharePoint" />

                    </td>

                </tr>

                <tr>

                    <td></td>

                </tr>

                <tr>

                    <td>

                        <asp:Label ID="lblLocalPath" runat="server" Text="Local Path:"></asp:Label>

                    </td>

                    <td>

                        <asp:FileUpload ID="FileLocalPath" Width="350" runat="server" />

                    </td>

                </tr>

                <tr>

                    <td>

                        <asp:Label ID="lblSharePointURL" runat="server" Text="SharePoint Site URL:"></asp:Label>

                    </td>

                    <td>

                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtSharePointURL" Width="350" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

                    </td>

                </tr>

                <tr>

                    <td>

                        <asp:Label ID="lblLibraryName" runat="server" Text="Library Name:"></asp:Label>

                    </td>

                    <td>

                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtLibraryName" Width="350" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

                    </td>

                </tr>

                <tr>

                    <td colspan="2" align="right">

                        <asp:Button ID="btnUpload" runat="server" Text="Upload" OnClick="btnUpload_Click" />

                    </td>

                </tr>

                <tr>

                    <td colspan="2">

                        <asp:Label ID="lblMsg" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>

                    </td>

                </tr>

            </table>

        </div>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is my upload.aspx.cs

```
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication7
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public ClientContext SPClientContext { get; set; }

        public Web SPWeb { get; set; }

        public string SPErrorMsg { get; set; }

        protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

        {
            try
            {


                string sURL = txtSharePointURL.Text;

                string sDocName = string.Empty;

                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sURL) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtLibraryName.Text) && (FileLocalPath.HasFile))
                {

                    bool bbConnected = Connect(sURL, "abhishekr", "A123bhishek", "saras");

                    if (bbConnected)
                    {

                        Uri uri = new Uri(sURL);

                        string sSPSiteRelativeURL = uri.AbsolutePath;

                        sDocName = UploadFile(FileLocalPath.FileContent, FileLocalPath.FileName, sSPSiteRelativeURL, txtLibraryName.Text);

                        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sDocName))
                        {

                            lblMsg.Text = "The document " + sDocName + " has been uploaded successfully..";

                            lblMsg.ForeColor = Color.Blue;

                        }

                        else
                        {

                            lblMsg.Text = SPErrorMsg;

                            lblMsg.ForeColor = Color.Red;

                        }

                    }

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Write(ex.Message.ToString());
            }

        }



        public bool Connect(string SPURL, string SPUserName, string SPPassWord, string SPDomainName)
        {

            bool bConnected = false;

            try
            {

                SPClientContext = new ClientContext(SPURL);

                SPClientContext.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(SPUserName, SPPassWord, SPDomainName);

                SPWeb = SPClientContext.Web;

                SPClientContext.Load(SPWeb);

                SPClientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                bConnected = true;

            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                bConnected = false;

                SPErrorMsg = ex.Message;
                Response.Write(ex.Message.ToString());

            }

            return bConnected;

        }



        public string UploadFile(Stream fs, string sFileName, string sSPSiteRelativeURL, string sLibraryName)
        {

            string sDocName = string.Empty;

            try
            {

                if (SPWeb != null)
                {

                    var sFileUrl = String.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}", sSPSiteRelativeURL, sLibraryName, sFileName);



                    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.SaveBinaryDirect(SPClientContext, sFileUrl, fs, true);



                    sDocName = sFileName;

                }

            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                sDocName = string.Empty;

                SPErrorMsg = ex.Message;
                Response.Write(ex.Message.ToString());

            }



            return sDocName;

        }
    }
}
```

it is working fine when i am uploading small files, it through an error when i uploading large file.

Error:" Maximum request length exceeded "

Please, help me how to resolve issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can define max request length in SharePoint like this: 
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/sammykailini/2013/11/06/how-to-increase-the-maximum-upload-size-in-sharepoint-2013/

In Central Admin>Application Management>Manage Web Applications> Select the desired web app and click General Settings on the ribbon

In web.config edit httpRuntime Node like this (for 2GB files and unlimited execution):

Comment: What maximum size did you configure?

Comment: i have configure the 500 MB, and when i am uploading even  20 MB  file  i got error.

Comment: check C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\80 web.config file for <httpRuntime maxRequestLength attribute

Comment: i check there is no wss folder after wwwroot ,check and provide me proper path.

Comment: Go to your server, open IIS, open Web Application (probably: Portal:80), then in the upper right corner of iis manager click explore to open up the directory.

Comment: yes , i checked it ,this is  my configuration   <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="51200" requestValidationMode="2.0" />

Comment: That's 50MB - I presume you get a timeout when uploading 20MB. - add executionTimeout="999999" so the connections stays open while uploading.